# CSS Responsive Footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, stylesheet

The majority of the site displays well in all browsers including mobile except for the footer.

In 1600X900 dimensions the footer displays perfectly.  On sites where the resolution height is below 900, the footer disappears.  I've tried everything I could think of to have the footer "snap" to the bottom of the screen and am clearly out of my realm of expertise. Tested using the latest Chrome and Firefox with similar/same results (that is good I guess, LOL).

How do I have the bottom black elements snap to the bottom of the page?

URL of website: http://bit.ly/1ro8FtA

Screenshot at different dimensions: http://bit.ly/1uLGgNX

Comment: What about adding some code?
PS : looking at it with "View page source" is cool, but someday your site may disappear and then people which might have the same problem as you do won't be able to find helpful information.

Comment: Your footer is working great from my computer. Are you sure you don't have any cache issue ?

Comment: I agree with @KevinLabécot it does

Comment: What dimensions are you guys viewing at though?  It's only below a 900 height that the problems occurs.

Comment: I think you are looking fixed position footer. try to use `position:fixed; bottom:0;` for your footer class.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Tested from +1200 height to 400px with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (if you only want to move your Footer and not the all black region), try to change your CSS:

```
.agentpress-pro-black .site-footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to this:

```
.agentpress-pro-black .site-footer {
    background-color: #000000;       
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; /*new*/
    bottom: 0; /*new*/
    position: fixed; /*new*/
}
```

**NOTE**

If you want all black region, then you should change your HTML, and  move all your black region in order to have one positioning container fixed

Comment: @Benjamin I'm not quiet sure if OP only wants the Footer, if so, this code works, but if OP wants the all BLACK regions then OP had 2 more divs to position.

Comment: I hope better he can wrap them all in a separate container and positioning will fix OP's issue.

Comment: Ya I was about to say that, if OP's want to move all black region then OP should change his HTML in order to have one positioning container fixed

Comment: I'm gonna add this to my answer :)

Comment: That will be great if you do and i will give you another +1 for that :)

Comment: Perfect, I think this will work, I'll dig in an make the changes to all of them...it's posters like you that are why I love Stack...thanks for the help!